# Complex conditional formatting based on values of some cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet like following

```
  | A     | B    | C    |
1 | Name1 | a    | b    |
2 |       | key1 | val1 | 
3 |       | key2 | val2 |
4 |       | key3 | val3 |
5 | Name2 | a    | b    |
6 |       | key1 | val1 | 
7 |       | key2 | val4 |
8 |       | key3 | val5 |
```

What I want to do, is `if (C1 = 'b') then format C2:C4` then highlight all `val#` cells that are duplicate. So in the table above cells `val1` would be highlighted.
Is this possible at all?

Comment: In your table there are no cells where `a=b`.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the question. Misspelled what I meant originally.

Comment: I think first of all you need to find a way to tell if a value is duplicate. You can start by using an auxiliary column on the right, which should have a '1' if the value at its left appears above or below it. Then apply conditional format based on $C$1 and the cell on its right. If that works, then you can try to merge all the logic in the conditional formatting.

Comment: I think you need to think about a better way to describe what "What I want to do, is if (C1 = 'b') then format C2:C4 then highlight all val# cells that are duplicate" means. I'm lost, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this achieves what you ask (though why you want that is another matter):

Clear any existing CF from ColumnC, select ColumnC and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(AND(C$1="b",ROW()<5),MATCH(C1,C$2:C$4,0))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select highlighting of choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Repeat for the other three colours, adjusting the text and formatting to suit.